# How to pivot mysql rows to columns simple way

Tags: mysql, sql, pivot

[image]

How do I query the database to return something like

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use conditional aggregation:

```
select id,
       avg(case when semester = 20081 then IP_Semester end) as sem_20081,
       avg(case when semester = 20082 then IP_Semester end) as sem_20082,
       . . .
from t
group by id;
```

Comment: ok tq

how about this query that will be wrong
create table tess
select Identifier,
       avg(case when semester = 20081 then IP_Semester end) as sem_20081,
       avg(case when semester = 20082 then IP_Semester end) as sem_20082,
       avg(case when semester = 20091 then IP_Semester end) as sem_20091,
       avg(case when semester = 20092 then IP_Semester end) as sem_20092
from angktn2008
group by Identifier